# Why should i include the namespace in each aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, namespaces, code-behind

I usually include my namespaces e.g.

```
using myProject.Model;
```

to my .cs files 
but when i want to iterate an object derived from myProject.Model in my .aspx file i must always include the directive

```
<%@ Import Namespace="myProject.Model" %>
```

Why is that? I mean if it is declared in code behind file (in default.aspx.cs) of default.aspx  Why should i add it again? Why it is not available?

Just wondering but i would like to know why is that.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Those two files are, for compilation purposes, independent, as the `aspx` is compiled with different compiler than `cs`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a [namespaces element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164642(v=vs.80).aspx) to your web.config to specify namespaces that you'd like to be imported automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Because the ASPX pages are compiled using a different "WebPage" compiler, you must specify the namespaces for each page on wich you requrire certain features form that namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `@Import` directive allows you to specify the namespaces to be imported for the Asp.Net pages or user controls, while `import` keyword is used to specify the namespaces to be imported for the codebehind.