# Namespace is found in class, but not in aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, namespaces

I'm having trouble with the namespace `System.Net.Http`.

I want to use, e.g. HttpClient, from the namespace `System.Net.Http`. When I use `using System.Net.Http;` in a C# class, I can use HttpClient just fine, but when I try to import the namespace in an aspx file, like this: `%@ Import Namespace="System.Net.Http" %>` it won't regonize HttpClient:

> The type or namespace name 'HttpClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I've already installed it like [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http) and added it to my references by doing [this](https://i.gyazo.com/4389a17b73f4cfa1ee13b40c5bac2bf1.png).

How do I use, e.g. HttpClient, in my .aspx file like I use it in a C# class?

**UPDATE**

This is not a duplicate of [Why should i include the namespace in each aspx page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12425114/why-should-i-include-the-namespace-in-each-aspx-page), because I'm not asking how I'm supposed to include a namespace in every class.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12425114/why-should-i-include-the-namespace-in-each-aspx-page

Comment: @Thiru nope, different question here.

Comment: Because the ASPX pages are compiled using a different "WebPage" compiler. If you want use the namespace in aspx pages add it in web.config file check this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164642(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First it is worth pointing out that you probably shouldn't do this.  You should probably prepare the data you need in the Page_Load event and just display it on the WebForms page.  If you still want to do it this way, I am pretty sure what is happening is that you have a dependent assembly other than System.Web.HttpClient.  Have a look at your CodeBehind page and make sure all imports are there in the aspx page for every using in the CodeBehind. In other words:

System.Web.HttpClient depends on another assembly you are not referencing.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know how CodeBehind works exactly, but it is pretty simple :) It is basically the class of the .apsx file (for those who don't know that)